# JRuby to use Java system.console

Tags: console, passwords, jruby

Im new to Jruby and I need some help with this code. I know im doing this wrong. I really need help with how to get this right.

What am I doing? Mask user password input in JRuby.
Plan: Use java's System.console to do it.

code:

```
require "rubygems"
require "java"

include_class 'java.io.PrintStream'
include_class 'java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream'
include_class 'java.lang.System'
include_class 'java.io.Console'



Console console = System.console();
String password = console.readPassword("Enter password: ");

puts password
```

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

it needs to be converted from `char[]` back into a String object, something like this:

```
require "java"

include_class 'java.lang.System'
include_class 'java.io.Console'

console = System.console();
password = console.readPassword("Enter password: ");

passwordString = java.lang.String.new(password)

printf("%s\n", passwordString )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the password into a `char[]`, convert it to a `java.lang.String`, and then convert that into a Ruby `String`:

```
require 'java'
include_class 'java.lang.System'
include_class 'java.io.Console'

# Read the password into a char[]
java_char_array = System.console.readPassword("password:")

# Turn that into a java.lang.String
java_string = java.lang.String.new(java_char_array)

# Turn this into a Ruby string and strip off the newline.
password = java_string.to_s.strip
```

The reason that `read_password` gives you back a `char[]` is a bit complicated, but it boils down to a big song and dance about security. You can use `Array.fill` to nuke the contents of `char[]` and thus keep the password from ending up sitting around in memory for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
console = System.console();
String password = console.readPassword("Enter password: ");

puts password
```